# Can't register click events in html BrowserWindow within Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have been following through a tutorial for Electron and I am using a html document in a new BrowserWindow as a pop-up. The problem is, when I use an onclick handler on a html tag, it doesn't seem to fire. If I open the developer tools, I can type my function into the console and it behaves as expected!

Not sure if I'm missing something really obvious here but would appreciate anyone who could help me solve the issue.

Here is the body tag from the html for BrowserWindow:

```
<body id="page-info">
  <main class="info-content">
    <h3 class="page-headline">Wisdom Pet</h3>
    <p>Welcome to the Wisdom Pet App.<br>
    <strong>Version 1.0.0</strong><br>
    <small>Built with love by <a href="#" onclick="shell.openExternal('http://raybo.org')">Ray Villalobos</a></small>
    </p>
    <p><a href="#" id="closeAbout" onclick="send()">close window</a></p>
  </main>

<script type="text/javascript">enter code here
    var electron = require('electron');
    var shell = electron.shell;
    var ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

    /* Also tried using event listeners without html onclick

    var closeAbout= document.getElementById("closeAbout");
    closeAbout.addEventListener("click", function(){
        send();
    });
    */

    function send(){

        console.log("sending...");
        ipc.sendSync('closeInfoWindow')
    }
</script>
```

And here is the main.js file:

```
var Electron = require("electron");
var Menu = Electron.Menu;
var BrowserWindow = Electron.BrowserWindow;
var app = Electron.app;
var ipc = Electron.ipcMain;

var myAppMenu, menuTemplate;

app.on("ready", function(){

  var appWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false
  });

  appWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/index.html");

  var infoWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,

  });

  infoWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/info.html');

  appWindow.once("ready-to-show", function(){
    appWindow.show();
  });

  ipc.on("openInfoWindow", function(event, arg){
    event.returnValue = "";
    infoWindow.show();
  })

  ipc.on('closeInfoWindow', function(event, arg){
    event.returnValue = '';
    infoWindow.hide();
  }); //closeInfoWindow
```

});

The ipc.on("openInfoWindow") work fine from the main window, but once the infoWindow is open, I can't close it unless I send the code directly from the developer tools.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?  I tried your example and I see the "sending...." being printed to the console.

Comment: No errors at all. I only see the console log when I manually type the send() call into the developer tools... It's as if the onclick isn't responding. I have also tried using addEventListener to listen for a click event and to fire the function that way but that does nothing either. Really confused!

I am also using react in other areas of the application, and onClick events are working fine.